# How to integrate and setup CircleCI for flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, circleci, flutter-test

I am struggling how to integrate and setup CircleCI for flutter web. May I get information to setting up CircleCI for flutter web NOT flutter app. Thanks!